# cannot convert 'Cards' to 'int' - C++ Compile Error

Tags: c++

The purpose of the current code is to create struct-based objects for the playing cards, with int attributes to store value and suit. After you assign create a deck with the values.

I'm trying to assign values of cards to a 2D array. I'm getting the error:

```
error: cannot convert 'Cards' to 'int' in assignment
```

Can I not assign an int value the same value as Cards's int value? Shouldn't it be the same as int x = y?

```
struct Cards
{
  int value;
  int suit;
};

Cards assignCards(int, int);

main()
{ 
  // Card creation
  Cards hearts[13];
  Cards diamonds[13];
  Cards spades[13];
  Cards clubs[13];

  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) // Card assignment
  {
    hearts[i] = assignCards(0, i);
    diamonds[i] = assignCards(1, i);
    spades[i] = assignCards(2, i);
    clubs[i] = assignCards(3, i);
  }

  // Deck and Hand creation [suit][value]
  int deck[4][13];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    if (i == 0)
      for (int j = 0; j < 13; i++)
        deck[i][j] = hearts[j];

    if (i == 1)
      for (int j = 0; j < 13; i++)
        deck[i][j] = diamonds[j];

    if (i == 2)
      for (int j = 0; j < 13; i++)
        deck[i][j] = spades[j];

    if (i == 3)
      for (int j = 0; j < 13; i++)
        deck[i][j] = clubs[j];
  }

}

Cards assignCards(int y, int i)
{
  Cards x;
  x.value = i;
  x.suit = y;

  return x;
}
```

I'm relatively new to stackoverflow. I'm sorry if I'm missing any information.

Comment: `Can I not assign an int value the same value as Cards's int value?` A Card object is not the same as one of Cards two int values.

Comment: `int deck[4][13]` should be `Cards deck[4][13]`.

Comment: (`Cards` should be named `Card`)

Comment: It's really helpful if, rather than entering your entire program into StackOverflow, you cull it down to the minimum number of lines that generate the error. Sometimes that's just one or two. It's useful because then you'll find people here will focus on exactly what your problem is, and the exercise itself of cutting code down to the bare bones of an error often reveals the solution or close to it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll It's helped me a lot. Thanks for the help with posting here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't.
You can use something like:

```
    deck[i][j] = hearts[j].value;
```

Comment: I saw that I missed that a few minutes after I posted. It hurts a little.

Answer (score 1):

Every `deck[i][j]` is an `int` while `hearts[j]`, `diamonds[j]`, `spades[j]` and `clubs[j]` are `Cards` which can't obviously be converted to `int`.

```
int deck[4][13];
```

should be

```
Cards deck[4][13];
```

Your function

```
Cards assignCards(int y, int i);
```

would be better as constructor:

```
struct Card // singular is more appropriate
{
  int value;
  int suit;
  Card(int y, int i) : value(i), suit(y) {}
};
```

And you could change your loops as:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                     // ^ Careful: j not i
    deck[0][j] = hearts[j]   = Card(0, j);
    deck[1][j] = diamonds[j] = Card(1, j);
    deck[2][j] = spades[j]   = Card(2, j);
    deck[3][j] = clubs[j]    = Card(3, j);
}
```